# Travis builds on Ruby 2.6.3 have bundler version mismatch

Tags: ruby, travis-ci

When we upgraded our Rails app to use 2.6.3, with the version specified in

- `.ruby-version`
- `Gemfile`
- `.travis.yml`

we get the problem that the "system bundler" with Ruby 2.6.3 is not the same version as the latest version of `bundler` which is 2.0.1

So we get this error message

```
Fetching bundler-2.0.1.gem
bundler's executable "bundle" conflicts with /home/travis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/bin/bundle
Overwrite the executable? [yN]  

No output has been received in the last 10m0s, this potentially indicates a stalled build or something wrong with the build itself.
Check the details on how to adjust your build configuration on: https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/common-build-problems/#Build-times-out-because-no-output-was-received

The build has been terminated
```

This doesn't happen with Ruby 2.5.3. I am guessing if we added a pre-install step to maybe delete the system bundler that would solve the problem. Would there be any other solutions?

Comment: Ruby 2.6 comes with bundler installed by default, so two things come to mind that might be causing the issue:

1) In your travis.yml you may be manually downloading bundler. If so, you can remove that line.
2) You could try clearing your travis cache and running the build again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried a `before_install` step to upgrade `bundler` before it attempts `bundle gem install`?

```
before_install: gem update bundler
```